# exchange variables between html files in javascript

Tags: javascript, session, global-variables

I am trying to share variables between two html pages. I am only using javascript and HTML5 to develop a windows 8 app. Based on an image which a user clicks on one page, I want a div on a second page to be populated with that image. Any ideas?

When I click on the image, I am currently calling the following function:

```
function imageClick(url) {
             //var id = parsed.ClientID;
             //window.location= url + "?" + id
             window.location = url;
         }
```

Then in my html file, I have this line:

```
<img onclick="imageClick('pages/page2/page2.html')" 
data-win-bind="src:image" style="width: 133px; height: 125.5px;">
```

I was thinking of getting that id in the next page's url (if I were to uncomment the commented lines above) but it's a bit hackky and I don't actually know how to go about executing the retrieval of that on the next page..

Is there a more efficient and easy way of doing this in javascript? Like an equivalent of sessions in php or something?

Comment: Try `sessionStorage`, `localStorage`.

Comment: store the image source Location  in `localStorage`... on page 2 on body load read the location from `localStorage` shwo in div

Answer (score 0):

Add the link to the image to the query part of the url when they click. Something like you had in the comment, assuming you don't have a query part already:

```
function imageClick(url) {
         //var id = parsed.ClientID;
         window.location= url + "?src=" + url.src;
         //window.location = url;
     }
```

The other page can use `window.location.search` to extract it, strip off the `src=`. The code would look something like this:

```
var src = window.location.search;
if (src.indexOf("src=") == 0) {
    src = src.substring(4);
}
newPageImageElement.src = src;
```

Where `newPageImageElement` is the `<img>` where you want to display the picture on the second page.

Comment: @ Lee Meador Thanks for your response. I tried the method outlined above and got the following error: Unable to get property 'indexOf' of undefined or null reference

Comment: My mistake. It's not `query` but `search`. Fixed the code above. To understand more about what I'm doing, look into ways to parse the `window.location` to extract the link from the part of the URL after the question mark (?).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have session variables because it runs on the client side. You can use URL parameters and cookies in order to achieve the same results.

You can get the URL parameter by using this function:

http://ziemecki.net/content/javascript-parsing-url-parameters